# Python re.sub issue

Tags: python, regex, string, scrapy

I am trying to clean a string using `re.sub` to transform text to a time. My initial string is `"Durée : 1h30"` and I want to delete `"Durée : "` and to get this output: `"1h30"`. However with my current code, the output is this list of string: `["D", "u", "r", "é", "e", " ", ":", " ", "1", "h", "3", "0"]`.

```
for href in response.xpath("//div[@class='item']/a[@class='roll-2']//@href"):
        url = "https://www.louvre.fr" + href.extract()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

lenght = response.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/text()").extract()[1]  #lenght = "Durée : 1h30"

item['lenght'] = [re.sub("Durée : ", "", le) for le in lenght]
```

Comment: Why `[re.sub("Durée : ", "", le) for le in lenght]` and not  `[re.sub("Durée : ", "", lenght)` ?

Comment: You're iterating through every character of the string, for some reason. There's no need, and this is directly causing your strange output.

Comment: @DeepSpace Because xpath method return a list so this was the only way i found to make it works without getting the error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute... (Im a total newbie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are iterable in Python, and you're iterating over each character inside the list comprehension and running `re.sub` in those characters separately.

Also, you don't need Regex here. Use **`str.replace`**:

```
item['length'] = [length.replace('Durée : ', '')]
```